# WebDAV alternative in a PHP server

Tags: php, webdav

I'm currently exposing a WebDAV server using [SabrePHP](http://sabre.io/) which allows me to expose a virtual filesystem based on a MongoDB database and a GridFS implementation to store files.

Now, it works quite well with Cyberduck, but here's the problem, only with Cyberduck. I smashed my head against the walls more than once to make the authentication work with the Windows built-in DAV client implementation just to see that it required special headers and authentication strategy to work.

So I'd like to know if there is any kind of alternative to WebDAV. My first thought was FTP, but I don't know if it is possible to expose an FTP "server" in PHP (cheating with the protocol in some dark apache configuration), and if it will work with my whole filesystem stored in database.

Comment: What about SMB? Couldn't you make it seem like a network folder on Windows using SMB? I'm not familiar with GridFS so not sure how you'd get it to work...

Comment: well apparently it uses its own protocol (i.e. smb://) so i'd prefer using FTP which seems more suited if i need to do some hack. And gridFS is simply a mongoDB feature allowing to store and retrieve files in the database itself :)

Comment: To get things going on Windows, you might simply need HTTPS. Some more info here: http://sabre.io/dav/clients/windows/

Comment: Yup everything is ok on this side, I have full HTTPS with HTTP digest auth